# Oblique responsive line between 2 divs

Tags: css, svg

I would like to draw two oblique lines that would join two corners of two different divs. I need these lines to be responsive. My project currently uses angular but my problem, I think, can be solved with css. I also can't use external libraries.
[image]

I tried svg and I don't know if I used it wrong but it was not responsive.

```html
<svg width="220" height="240" class="roadLink"><line x1="50" y1="60" x2="530" y2="220" stroke="black"/></svg>
<div class="mb-2 d-flex">
  <div class=" d-flex justify-content-between roadSize topAnrpBlock">
  </div>
</div>
<svg width="140" height="100" class="roadLink"><line x1="50" y1="50" x2="500" y2="200" stroke="black"/></svg>
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: I tried the code above. The roadSize class is just a static widh and heigh and topAnprBlock is not used. RoadLink is just a position absolute and a color.

Comment: Wont you need some Javascript to find out where those corners are and do a little bit of calculation to find out what width and what start and end points the lines should have?